# Two orthonormal bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\{u_1, \dots, u_n\}$ and $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ are orthonormal bases. Define the $n \times n$ matrix
\begin{equation}
A = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \mu_j v_j \otimes u^t_j,
\end{equation}
where $\{\mu_j\}$ are complex numbers. Recall that $ v \otimes u^tx\ :=\ \langle x, u \rangle v $. What is determinant $A$?

-----------

I noticed that $Au_j = \mu_j v_j$, hence matrix $U$, which columns are vectors $u_j$, is change of basis matrix from basis $\{a_j\}$  (columns of matrix $A$) to basis $\{\mu_j V_j\}$. Intuition says $\det(A)= \mu_1 \mu_2\cdots\mu_n$

Comment: Isn't it easier to write $\langle x, v \rangle u$ instead of $v \otimes u^tx$? If they are equal, then $A$ is a vector, not a matrix.

Comment: Note that only $v \otimes u^t $ used in $A$ definition, not $v \otimes u^t x $.

Comment: I think you have that backwards. It should be $\langle x,u\rangle v$.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Oops... sorry... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In matrix notation, the formula is equivalent to:
$$
A = V M U^T
$$
where $V = \begin{bmatrix}v_1,v_2\ldots,v_n\end{bmatrix}$, $M=\text{diag}(\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots,\mu_n)$, $U = \begin{bmatrix}u_1,u_2\ldots,u_n\end{bmatrix}$.  If the values $\mu_j$ are nonnegative then this is the singular value decomposition of $A$. In any case, you can use the multiplicative property of the determinant.  Since $M$ is diagonal, its determinant is just the product of the values on the diagonal. 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\det(A) &= \det(V) \det(M) \det(U^T)\\
&= \det(U) \det(V) \mu_1 \mu_2 \ldots \mu_n
\end{aligned}
$$
The matrices $U$ and $V$ are orthonormal and have unit determinant. So we can conclude $|\det(A)| = |\mu_1 \mu_2 \ldots \mu_n|$, but the phase depends on the bases.

Comment: There's ambiguity even in $\mathbb{R}^1$. Take $u_1=-1, \mu_1 = 1, v_1=1$, then $\mu_1=1$ but $\det(A)=-1$.

Comment: You are right, there is ambiguity, but it's only about the sign. The phase can't be anything but zero or $\pi$. It depends on whether the orientations of bases are the same